# Excel formula for 2 scales

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, formulas

I am trying to write a formula in excel for the following problem -

1. There are 2 scales, one from 85% - 93% & the other from 91%-94%
2. At 85% & 91% on 2 scales, the answer is 50%, similarly at 93% & 94% on 2 scales the answer is 71%.
3. I am not able to write a formula in a way that if the values on these scales lie in between these numbers i.e 86% & 92% respectively, I get one answer (assuming the increase is linear).

I can do it with only 1 scale. i.e if value is b/w 85%-93% at 94% on the other scale.
The formula for one scale is follows -

```
If(value < 93%),( value - 85%)/ (93% - 85%) * (71% - 58%) + 58%, NA
```

[image]

I need to write a formula in which if i have a value of 86% and 92% on the 2 scales, I get one value from the table.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you got the numbers right on your question?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand.  If this is for school, please write out the entire question.  If it's not, then provide some same data, expected output, and a little background information.  Also, please see [ask] and well as [mcve].

Comment: The numbers are right. Not a question for school. Real world calculation needed - 
An example of expected output will be - let's say you get 86% on the horizontal scale and 92% on the vertical scale.
What is your output then? theoretically it should be close to ~52% i.e the number lies b/w 85%-93% and b/w 91% - 94%.. so the answer should be more than 50% slightly.. 

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 2):

By inspection the formula should be

```
=50+(x-85)/8*13+(y-91)/3*8
```

where x is the value on the first scale and y is the value on the second scale.

If you look at either row, you can see that the result increases by 13% for a change in input of 8%, and if you look at either column you can see that the output increases by 8% for a change in input of 3%. That is starting from baseline of 50%.

If you wanted to do it more formally you could assume an equation of

```
z=ax+by+c
```

and solve it for any three values in the table. If the fourth value was consistent (which it is), it means that the assumption of linearity is correct. Or you could do a multiple regression.